# Dynamically Generated TextBoxes

Tags: c#, forms, variables, for-loop, dynamic

I need a way of dynamically creating a number of text boxes and accessing their values.

In my form the user enters a number between 1 and 50 and then that number of text boxes must be created with dynamic names ie ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3, ...ingredient50 etc.

I have a for loop that will create a number of text boxes using the value, but how do I store the text box value in a string variable?

Here is the for loop currently empty

```
int i = Form1.ingredientCount;

for (i = 1; i < Form1.ingredientCount; i++)
{
    //create new text box
    //create new string that then holds value from text box
}
```

For clarification:

A user enters a number on the previous page.

This number then determines the number of textboxes created and the number of strings created.

The textboxes and strings need to have uniquely generated IDs in a for loop.

I also need another textbox for the weight of each ingredient although I could figure that out myself.

So basically I want each text box and string to be named something like

`"input" + i` (where i is incrementer)
so that would make the name be "input1", "input2", "input3" and so on.

Same with the string which will contain data from textbox.

Comment: if the ingredients are supposed to be something like "yeast, "eggs", "sugar"...just pluck them from an array

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. I'm confused about where the textbox comes in, and what you mean by needing them to be in global variables. C# has several things that could be considered "global variables," but no concept that is actually called a "global variable," so it would be helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, I will try to explain in more detail

First of all a user enters a number
Then this number is used in a for loop
The for loop then needs to generate a new text box and a unique string name to store what the user then enters in each of these text boxes. So the string is basically reading the text box
ie
string1 = TextBox1.ToString()
string2 = TextBox2.ToString()
...
string50 = TextBox50.ToString()

Comment: that is what collections and arrays are for

Comment: I have never understood arrays, and hoped there was a way around it. I have trouble understanding how each bit of an array is written to and how each bit is read when needed.

Comment: I have clarified my issue, I hope this helps a bit more now.

Comment: `I have never understood arrays` sounds like a growth opportunity

Comment: Haha it probably is, it was one of my biggest weak points when studying Computing. I know what they are, the way they are programmed just seems confusing to me.

I have managed to make 2 games without using arrays and in comparison, this program should be relatively simple

Answer (score 0):

I thought i would edit it, as it seems i had misunderstood the question

you could bind it in the form as the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Recepie pancakes = new Recepie();
    IList<UniqueHolder> items = new List<UniqueHolder>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pancakes.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Title = "Milk - 250 gr" });
        pancakes.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Title = "Butter - 25 gr" });
        pancakes.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Title = "Oil - 1 large spoon" });
        pancakes.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Title = "Sugar - 100 gr" });
        pancakes.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient { Title = "Flower - 200 gr" });
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < pancakes.Ingredients.Count; i++)
        {
            Ingredient ing = pancakes.Ingredients[i];
            TextBox tb = new TextBox { Location = new Point(10, i * 30), Size = new Size(200, 20), Text = ing.Title };
            UniqueHolder uh = new UniqueHolder { Ingredient = ing, TextBox = tb };
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

The unique holder does the databinding on changes in either ingredient or textbox

```
public class UniqueHolder : IDisposable
{
    public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is UniqueHolder)
        {

            return Guid.Equals(((UniqueHolder)obj).UniqueID, this.UniqueID);
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return UniqueID.GetHashCode();
    }

    private TextBox textbox;
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get
        {
            return textbox;
        }
        set
        {
            if (object.Equals(textbox, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
            }
            textbox = value;
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private Ingredient ingredient;
    public Ingredient Ingredient 
    {
        get
        {
            return ingredient;
        }
        set
        {
            if (object.Equals(ingredient, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (ingredient != null)
            {
                ingredient.PropertyChanged -= OnIngredientChanged;
            }
            ingredient = value;
            if (ingredient != null)
            {
                ingredient.PropertyChanged += OnIngredientChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    public UniqueHolder()
    {
        this.UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    protected virtual void OnIngredientChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals(e.PropertyName, "Title", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (TextBox == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            TextBox.Text = Ingredient.Title;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Ingredient == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Ingredient.Title = tb.Text;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Ingredient = null;
        TextBox = null;
    }
}
```

And you can get back to the recepie using the ingredients as such

```
public class Recepie : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>();
    public IList<Ingredient> Ingredients
    {
        get
        {
            return ingredients;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnIngredientsListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                var ing = item as Ingredient;
                if (ing == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                ing.Recepie = null;
            }
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var ing = item as Ingredient;
                if (ing == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                ing.Recepie = this;
            }
        }
    }

    public Recepie()
    {
        var obs = Ingredients as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (obs != null)
        {
            obs.CollectionChanged += OnIngredientsListChanged;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        int total = Ingredients.Count;
        for (int i = total; --i >= 0; )
        {
            Ingredients.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        var obs = Ingredients as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (obs != null)
        {
            obs.CollectionChanged -= OnIngredientsListChanged;
        }
    }
}

public class Ingredient : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Recepie recepie;
    public virtual Recepie Recepie
    {
        get
        {
            return recepie;
        }
        set
        {
            if (object.Equals(recepie, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            recepie = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Recepie");
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.Equals(title, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var local = PropertyChanged;
        if (local != null)
        {
            local.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: guid creates random strings right? I need to be able to manipulate and access these strings later in the program. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Or is there a way that I can easily access their names later on?

Comment: Right, there is no reason you couldn't save the Guids in an Dictionary<Guid, Control> to get access to the textboxes afterwards (i wonder why i got downvoted the second after i posted this though...)

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted it, I can't downvote until I have a good reputation.

Could you please explain how to create the Guid and then add it to a dictionary? Would I need to create the dictionary outside the for loop and what does a dictionary do exactly? Thanks

Comment: How does the guild 'hold [the] value from text box' as asked?

Comment: @stuartd: i only mentioned the Guid to point out that this is the easiest way in creating Unique ID's, as what i thought he was asking when the question was first posed (and honestly, i mistook commentbox for answerbox :)). But i did my best to make a bit better implementation and it seems, i don't really need a Guid...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a string to hold the value from the textboxes, keep the textboxes in a list and get the value out from the Text property when you need it: then you don't need to wire up the TextChanged event etc. Edit: you don't need a string variable to store the textbox text, as you now have a reference to that via the list and the Text property when it's needed.

```
// a field 
List<TextBox> ingredientTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

private void Populate(int ingredientCount)
{
    for (i = 1; i < ingredientCount; i++)
    {
        // Assign a consecutive name so can order by it
        TextBox tb = new TextBox { Name = "IngredientTextbox" + i};
        ingredientTextBoxes.Add(tb);
    }
}

// when you want the ingredients
public List<string> GetIngredients
{
    List<string> ingredients = new List<string>();

    foreach (var tb in ingredientTextBoxes)
    {
        ingredients.Add(tb.text);
    }

    return ingredients;
}

// contains
private List<string> GetIngredientsMatching(string match)
{
    // Contains really should take a StringComparison parameter, but it doesn't
    return ingredientTextBoxes
                    .Where(t => t.Text.ToUpper().Contains(match.ToUpper()))
                    .Select(t => t.Text);
}
```

Edit: if you're going to have multiple values per ingredient then use a User Control which exposes the properties you want - summarising amount, weight, description (e.g. "a pinch" of salt) - in the most convenient way for the code accessing these properties.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the perfect solution I was looking for. Very much appreciated, sadly I can't upvote yet otherwise I would.

But one more thing, how would I then read that string?

Later in the program I will need to use .Contains() so how would I address an individual string for that?

Comment: @KieranWarren the text is always available directly from the text box controls, and you're keeping them in a list. See edit. Though you can't up vote, if this is the answer to your question, you can mark it as such by clicking the tick next to the answer.